# Difficult partial solution to a reccurence equation

Tags: recurrence-relations

I am trying to help a friend of mine solve

$$ a_n + 5 a_{n-1} + 6 a_{n-2} = 12n - 2(-1)^n$$

Now the homogenous solution is easy to find, and one
just needs to solve the equation $r^2 + 5r + 6 = 0$
Which has roots $r=-2$ and $r-3$, so the homogenous solution is

$$A (-2)^n + B (-3)^n$$

Which can be confirmed by putting it into the equation. 
Now usually I would guess that the particular solution was on the form

$$h_p = (An + B) + C(-1)^n$$

but this is clearly wrong, is there any other way to find the solution of the equation ?

Comment: In fact it is not so simple to guess the form of the particular solution for the inhomogenous term $(-1)^n$ : http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=a%28n%29%2B5a%28n-1%29%2B6a%28n-2%29%3D12n-2%28-1%29%5En

Comment: What's clearly wrong about it?  It seems to work for $A=1$, $B=17/12$, and $C=-1$.

Comment: And in what whay is that equal to $12n - 2(-1)^n$ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you assumed for the particular solution is correct. However, if you do not want to deal with inhomogeneous difference equations and guessing your particular solution, then you can use the [following technique](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/205372/how-to-solve-this-recurrence-relation-f-n-3f-n-1-12-1n/205491#205491) to transform it to a homogeneous difference equation. Another efficient technique is the [Z-transform technique](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-transform).