# Recurrence relations help please?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

How do I solve this recurrence relation?

$$
a_k = a_{k-1} + k
$$
when $a_0 = 2$.

Comment: See also [Telescoping Series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Solving the recurrence relation $T(n)=T(n-1)+cn$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/217162/solving-the-recurrence-relation-tn-tn-1cn)

Answer (score 3):

**hint**: $a_k = (a_k-a_{k-1})+(a_{k-1}-a_{k-2})+\cdots + (a_2-a_1) +(a_1-a_0)+a_0 = k+(k-1)+(k-2)+\cdots + 2+1+2$

Answer (score 2):

Note that
$$ a_k - a_{k-1} = k, $$
so
$$ a_{n}-a_0 = \sum_{k=1}^{n} (a_k-a_{k-1}) = \sum_{k=1}^n k = \frac{1}{2}n(n+1). $$