# Recurrence equation for $T(n)=T(n-1)+cn$ by substitution (induction)

Tags: algorithms, induction, recurrence-relations, recursion, recursive-algorithms

I was able to solve this relation as described here
[Solving the recurrence relation $T(n)=T(n-1)+cn$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/217162/solving-the-recurrence-relation-tn-tn-1cn)

By the way, my exercises asks also to demostrate by "substitution" and "induction" why the result shall be $T(n) = O(n^2)$

This is what I tried:

$Goal$ We shall demostrate that T(n)<=$O(n^2)$ 
Where

- T(1) = c' if n=1 (c' is a constant greater than zero)
- T(n) = T(n-1) + cn if n>1 (c is a constant greater than zero)

Thesis: Exists some d>0 such as $T(n) <= dn^2$. d is a positive constant.

Base case (with n=1)  
$T(1) = c' <= d(1^2)$ Hence true dor any d>=c'.

Induction hypotesis: the thesis is still true for any m<n.

| Equation | Applied hypotesis | Our constraint |
| --- | --- | --- |
| $T(n) = T(n-1) + cn $ | $<= d(n-1)^2+cn$ $= dn^2-2dn-d+cn$ | <= dn^2 |

Now, solving the equation  
$dn^2-2dn-d+cn <= dn^2 $ 
$-2dn-d+cn <= 0 $ 
$cn <= 2dn+d $

Then I stuck, I cannot demostrate for d because n is still there, normally I will get some kind of semplification where can I get something like true for all c greater than ...

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You did not say who's $d$. <> for better formatting, please use `\leq` ($\leq$) or `leqslant` ($\leqslant$) instead of $<=$. (`leq` stands for **l**esser than or **eq**ual to. Same thing with `\geq` and `\geqslant` will produce the greater than or equal sign)

Comment: @Didier 
Thesis: Exists some d>0 such as $T(n) \leq dn2$. d is a positive constant.

d shall be an arbitrary constants, that shall exists and be greter than zero, to demostrate that the algorithm can be in the order of $n^2$. In trying then to replace the original equation with my $dn^2$. Is now more understandable?

Comment: I didn't say that you were not understandable. I said that you did not defined $d$. My point is: if you assume that such a $d$ exists at order $n$, and you manage to show that the **same** $d$ works at order $n+1$, this is still not a proof: you did not show that it exists.

Answer (score 3):

You can solve the recurrence like this. We have $$T(1) = T(0) + c.$$ Then $$T(2) = T(1) + 2c = T(0) + c(1 + 2).$$ Then $$T(3) = T(2) + 3c = T(0) + c(1+2+3).$$ When you do this repeatedly, you get that $$T(n) = T(0) + c(1 + 2 + 3 + \dots + n).$$ Can you finish the problem from here?

Comment: Yes I can, that is what I found called iterative method (actually I usually try with the top-down approach, I think this shall be the bottom up). 
Marked this, I was trying to understand the substitution way, where I shall demonstrate by induction that, an already given result is valid. I'm not sure to have understood how to resolve it by that way.

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to guess one possible value for $d$.
To that end, check for the first values of $n$:

- $n=1$: we have $T(1) = c + T(0)$.
  Therefore, $|T(1)| \leqslant |c| + |T(0)|$.
- $n=2$: we have $|T(2)| = 2c + T(1) = 3c + T(0)$.
  Therefore, $T(2) \leqslant 2|c| + |T(0)|$.
- $n=3$: we have $T(3) = 3c + T(2) = 5c + T(0)$.
  Therefore, we have $|T(3)| \leqslant 3|c| + |T(0)|$.

One remarks that, defining $d= 2\max\{|c|,|T(0)|\}$ for instance, we have:
$$
\forall n \in \{1,2,3\},\quad |T(n)| \leqslant d n^2.
$$

So, now, can you go on from there and show the result by induction with $d=2\max\{|c|,|T(0)|\}$?

(Note that this is just one possible value for $d$, which need not be optimal)