# Solving Recursions like this

Tags: recursion

> How can i solve this equation? I am really stuck
>
> $T(n) = T(n + 1) + T(n + 2) + 3n + 1$
>
> $T(0)=2$
>
> $T(1)=3$

Comment: First you solve the homogeneous version (without the $3n+1$), using the characteristic equation.

Comment: A usual way to do that is to solve the [homogeneous part](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation#Linear_homogeneous_recurrence_relations_with_constant_coefficients). And then to find a particular solution by the method of undetermnined coefficients. Finally sum these two and determine the constants thanks to the initial conditions.

Comment: Here is the [method](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/209640/solving-a-recurrence-relation-with-the-characteristic-equation/209652#209652). Do not forget to upvote the answers if you benefit from them.

Comment: [Another technique](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/205372/how-to-solve-this-recurrence-relation-f-n-3f-n-1-12-1n/205491#205491).

Comment: @vadim123: Just scroll the page down till you reach the answer you want and then copy the address.

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal, thanks I was being dense.

Answer (score 6):

Setting $S_n=T(n)+3n$, you'll obtain
$$
S_n=S_{n+1}+S_{n+2}-8.
$$

Comment: Just set $F_n=T(n)+3n-8$ immediately and you obtain the Fibonacci recursion.

Comment: @Raskolnikov: Certainly.