# Find the closed solution of $s_{n} = 3s_{n-1} + 2^{n-2} - 1$

Tags: recurrence-relations

Find the closed solution of $s_{n} = 3s_{n-1} + 2^{n-2} - 1$ if $s_1 = 0, s_2 = 0, s_3 = 1$

I have attempted to use $p_n = c2^{n-2} - d$ [where $h_n = A(3)^n$, but to no avail] - i ended up with $c=-1$ and $d=-\frac{1}{2}$, which is incorrect.

Any help is appreciated! Thanks.

Edit: solution I require is $\frac{1}{2} (3^{n-1}+1-2^n)$

Edit2: Solutions to the homogeneous equation would be of the form $h_n = A(\alpha)^n + B(\beta)^n$, and $p_n$ will exist such that $s_n = h_n + p_n$

Comment: [Here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/209640/solving-a-recurrence-relation-with-the-characteristic-equation/209652#209652) is the technique.

Comment: [Here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/205372/how-to-solve-this-recurrence-relation-f-n-3f-n-1-12-1n/205491#205491) is another way you can go.

Comment: @Mhenni My problem is I do not know the correct "guess" for $h_n$. If I know that, I am equipped to do the rest (the links you showed me aren't helpful in that regard). Uros, yes, I'm sure.

Comment: Use induction on n! That's the easiest way out there!

Comment: haha somabha, i was given the answers at the back of the book, how do i use induction otherwise? :P

Comment: You can't use induction if you don't have a formula. That is why using induction is not well suited to formulate solutions but to test them. You need to use other methods in general to solve recurrence relations, or else the whole topic would be trivial as most mathematicians are well versed in enough induction to check solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $ t_n := \frac{s_n}{3^n} $. Hence, $ t_n = t_{n-1} + 3^{-n}\left(2^{n-2} - 1\right) $. Also, $ t_1 = 0 $. Hence, $$ t_n = \sum_{k = 2}^n \frac{1}{4}\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^n - 3^{-n} $$ This is a geometric series and easily evaluated to arrive at  $$ t_n = \frac{1}{2}\cdot 3^{-n} \cdot \left(1 - 2^{n}\right) + \frac{1}{6} \implies s_n = \frac{1 + 3^{n-1}- 2^{n}}{2} $$

Comment: thank you! but i require to do it the substitution guessing method :\

Comment: The amount of notation you introduced without any sort of definitions makes it impossible to follow what you attempted. For one, you define $ p_n $ then don't even bother to use it. So I can't really tell where you went wrong or what you even tried. I did perform a substitution though, so it seems like you could refactor my solution into something you want.

Comment: added what they meant - maybe it's a unique method to our lecturer :P

Comment: never mind, got it, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A general technique is taught by Wilf's ["generatingfunctionology"](http://www.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/DownldGF.html). Define $S(z) = \sum_{n \ge 0} s_n z^n$ and write ($s_0$ you get from the recurrence "backwards", mostly for not having to mess around with indices):
$$
s_{n + 1} = 3 s_n + 2^{n - 1} - 1 \qquad s_0 = \frac{1}{6}
$$
Multiply the recurrence by $z^n$, add over $n \ge 0$ to get:
$$
\begin{align*}
\frac{S(z) - s_0}{z} 
  &= 3 S(z) + \frac{1}{2} \sum_{n \ge 0} 2^n z^n - \sum_{n \ge 0} z^n \\
  &= 3 S(z) + \frac{1}{2} \frac{1}{1 - 2 z} - \frac{1}{1 - z}
\end{align*}
$$
Solving for $S(z)$ and expanding in partial fractions:
$$
S(z) 
   = \frac{1}{6} \frac{1}{1 - 3 z} 
       - \frac{1}{2} \frac{1}{1 - 2 z}
       + \frac{1}{2} \frac{1}{1 - z}
$$
Everything in sight is geometric series:
$$
s_n = \frac{1}{6} \cdot 3^n - \frac{1}{2} \cdot 2^n + \frac{1}{2}
    = \frac{1}{2} \left( 3^{n - 1} - 2^{n - 1} + 1 \right)
$$