# Solving recurrence $T(n)=T(n-1)+3^{n-1}$

Tags: recurrence-relations

I have trouble solving following recurrence.

$$T(n)=T(n-1)+3^{n-1}$$

So far I tried annihilators but it doesn't work.

Comment: hint: sum these equations from n=1 to n=k

Comment: Here is a [technique](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/205372/how-to-solve-this-recurrence-relation-f-n-3f-n-1-12-1n/205491#205491).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's just $T(n) = C+\sum_{k=?}^n 3^{k-1}$, where the lower limit and the constant depend on base cases that you haven't given in the question.

The sum of powers of $3$ is a [finite geometric series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_geometric_series#Geometric_series) which has standard closed-form formulas.

Answer (score 0):

Another way (out of many). Denote $a_n=\frac{T_n}{3^{n-1}}$ to get
$$
a_n=\frac{1}{3} a_{n-1}+1=\frac{1}{3^2}a_{n-2}+\frac{1}{3}+1=\ldots \frac{1}{3^{n-1}}a_1+\sum_{k=0}^{n-2}\frac{1}{3^k}
$$
Hence
$$
T_n=T_1+3^n \cdot \frac{1-\frac{1}{3^{n-1}}}{1-\frac{1}{3}}
$$
Can you handle from here (note you didn't provide boundary value).