# Solving Recurrence equation

Tags: recurrence-relations

I have a problem with this type of recurrence equation.

Find the solution of recurrence equation:

$$T(1)=2,$$

$$T(n+1)=T(n)+2n , \quad \forall n\geq 1$$

Indeed,

I tired to Solving Recurrences Using Substitution

```
T(n)=T(n-1)+2(n-1)

T(n-1)=T(n-2)+2(n-2)

T(n-2)=T(n-3)+2(n-3)

T(n-3)=T(n-4)+2(n-4)

...............

T(4)=T(3)+2.3

T(3)=T(2)+2.2

T(2)=T(1)
```

I Sum up all these, and I got that:

$$T(n)=2(n-1)+2(n-2)+2(n-3)+...+2.3+2.2+2$$

but i'm stack there

1. Any help would be highly appreciated.
2. Can we Solving Recurrences Using Other methods suck like :

   ```
    The Characteristic Equation
   ```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are **many** methods. We describe one a little different than the one you were carrying out.

The homogeneous recurrence $T_{n+1}=T_n$ has as only solution $a_n=A$. This is immediate. But  to answer your last question, it **could** be thought of as using the characteristic equation method. The characteristic equation is the very uninteresting $x=1$. So the general solution of the homogenous recurrence is $A(1)^n$.

Now that we have the general solution of the homogeneous recurrence, we look for a *particular solution* of the original recurrence. *Guess* that it will be $T_n=an^2+bn+c$. Substituting in the original recurrence, we get
$$a(n+1)^2+b(n+1)+c=an^2+bn+c+2n.$$
Expand, and compare coefficients. We get $a=1$ and $a+b=0$, giving particular solution $n^2-n$.

Thus the general solution of our recurrence is $T_n=A+n^2-n$. To evaluate $A$, use the initial condition $T_1=2$.

**Remark:** You were **very** close to finding a particular solution. Let us take the expression you got at the end, take out the common factor $2$, and write it down backwards. We get
$$2(1+2+3+\cdots+(n-1)).$$
Recall that $1+2+3+\cdots +m=\frac{m(m+1)}{2}$. Putting $m=n-1$, we get $2\frac{(n-1)(n)}{2}$, that is, $n(n-1)$. That is exactly the particular solution obtained in the answer above.

Comment: Thanks sir,  but what is the exact answer is  T(n)=n(n−1) or T(n)=n(n−1)+2. i'm confusing could you please explain more

Comment: You need to evaluate $A$, using $T_1=2$. Substituting, we find that $A=2$, so the solution for the given initial condition is $2+n(n-1)$.

Answer (score 2):

You should merely recall that

$$1+2+\cdots+m=m\cdot(m+1)/2$$

Then, I think, $T(n)=n(n-1)+2$.

Answer (score 1):

As a general rule if $T(n+1) - T(n)$ is a polynomial of degree $k$ then $T(n)$ is a polynomial of degree $k+1$.  In this case, $T(n+1)-T(n)=2n$, a 1st-degree polynomial, so $T(n)$ is a 2nd-degree polynomial.

Thus, set $T(n)=A n^2 + B n + C$ where $A, B, C$ are coefficients to be determined.

Now plug that quadratic expression above into your recurrence relation, and you will end up with a system of equations in A, B, and C.  Solve that system and you are done.

Answer (score 1):

Related problems: [(I)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/886753/recurrence-of-the-form-2fn-fn1fn-13/886769#886769), [(II)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/680441/solve-the-non-homogeneous-recurrence-relation/680452#680452). Here is an approach

$$ T(n+1)=T(n)+2n , \quad \forall n\geq 1 \implies \sum_{k=1}^{n}(T(k+1)-T(k))=\sum_{k=1}^{n}2k $$

$$ \implies T(n+1)-T(1)=n(n+1)  \implies T(n+1)=n(n+1)+2  $$

$$ \implies T(n)=(n-1)n+2=n^2-2n+2. $$

If you are interested in other approaches see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/205372/how-to-solve-this-recurrence-relation-f-n-3f-n-1-12-1n/205491#205491).

Comment: you using Telescoping series Great idea

Comment: @Adam: Yes, and in this case it is very helpful.