# Guess explicit formula using iteration

Tags: sequences-and-series, recursion

The question ask us to guess an explicit formula for the sequence

$$s_k = s_{k-1} + 2k ,$$ for all integers $k$ greater than or equal to one and 
$s_0 = 3$

Can someone help me with this? Because I don't really understand how to do this.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: The first step in guessing a formula is to collect numerical data! Can you *at least* work out the first 10 terms of the sequence yourself? If not, then you don't understand what a recursively defined sequence is and you should reread your textbook or course notes.

Comment: But from my course notes, they look something like this: sk = s(k-1) + 2k; s(k-1) = s(k-2) + 2(k-1) and so on

Comment: You should start finding some terms to see what's going on.

Comment: @user3676752: I mean find *actual numbers*.  By definition $s_0$ is $3$. And what is $s_1$?  What is $s_2$? What is $s_3$? Use the recursion to figure out the first few terms of the sequence as real, specific, numbers. Writing $s_{k-1} = s_{k-2} + 2(k-1)$ is not progress for collecting numerical data.

Comment: Otherwise [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/775956/solving-recurrence-equation) is a technique you can use.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Moving the $s_{k-1}$ term to the LHS of the equation, the recurrence relation reads:

$$s_{k}-s_{k-1}=2k.$$

You can solve this recurrence relation by simply summing both sides over $k$:

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}(s_{k}-s_{k-1})=2\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}k.$$

The sum on the LHS telescopes, while the sum on the RHS is a straightforward arithmetic progression. There are standard methods for finding nice closed forms for both series.

Answer (score 0):

Rearrange to get:

$$s_k - s_{k - 1} = 2k$$

If we do a summation on both sides, a humongous amount of cancellation occurs on the LHS:

$$\sum_{i = 1}^{k} (s_i - s_{i - 1}) = \sum_{i = 1}^k 2i$$
$$s_k - s_0 = 2\sum_{i = 1}^ki$$

The RHS is easy to evaluate. Now just shift $s_0$ over to get $s_k$.

Comment: How do i use substitution method to do this?

Comment: Substitution? What substitution?

Comment: Something like this(slide 5): http://slideplayer.us/slide/1422870/

Comment: You should have stated in the question that you wanted to use the substitution method to sole this particular recurrence relation.