# non homogeneous recurrence relation

Tags: recurrence-relations

I am trying to solve the non-homogeneous linear recurrence relation:

$$f(n) = 6f(n-1) - 5,\quad  f(0) = 2.$$

How do I go about doing it? This is so different from solving a homogeneous recurrence relation.

Comment: Here are some approaches [technique 1](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/205372/how-to-solve-this-recurrence-relation-f-n-3f-n-1-12-1n/205491#205491)  [technique 2](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/209640/solving-a-recurrence-relation-with-the-characteristic-equation/209652#209652).

Answer (score 2):

[This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/332923/12042) shows one elementary method of solving exactly this kind of problem. There are many others, most of them considerably more general; [this link](http://www.wikihow.com/Solve-Recurrence-Relations) gives an brief introduction to some of them. [This PDF](http://www.ee.ntu.edu.tw/~yen/courses/dm-s2012/Chap05.pdf) goes into considerably more detail.

Comment: You didn't link "This PDF".

Comment: @Gerry: Thanks. (The link was there, but I lifted it from the Google returns, so it was missing the `http://`.)

Answer (score 0):

Split the solution into a homogeneous solution $f_n^{(H)}$ and inhomogeneous solution $f_n^{(I)}$.  $f_n^{(H)}$ satisfies

$$f_n^{(H)} - 6 f_{n-1}^{(H)} = 0 \implies f_n^{(H)} = A\cdot 6^n$$

$f_n^{(I)}$ is found by a guess; in this case, we can guess that it is a constant, which we find to be $1$ by plugging an unknown constant into the recurrence relation.  Therefore

$$f_n =  A\cdot 6^n + 1$$

We find that $f_0=2 \implies A=1$.  Therefore

$$f_n =  6^n + 1$$

Answer (score 0):

If you like generating functions, define $F(z) = \sum_{n \ge 0} f(n) z^n$, write the recurrence with no subtractions in indices:
$$
f(n + 1) = 6 f(n) - 5
$$
multiply by $z^n$, sum over $n \ge 0$, and recognize the sums:
$$
\frac{F(z) - f(0)}{z} = 6 F(z) - 5 \frac{1}{1 - z}
$$
Now it is smooth sailing, get partial fractions:
$$
F(z) = \frac{1}{1 - 6 z} + \frac{1}{1 - z}
$$
and expand as geometric series:
$$
f(n) = 6^n + 1
$$