# Use the iteration to make an educated guess at an explicit formula for a sequenc

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

the sequence $\{a_n\}$ is defined by recursively as $a_0=3$ and $a_n=6a_{n-1}+2$ for all $n\geq0$

Use the iteration to make an educated   guess at an explicit formula for a sequence

**My attempt:** $a_0=3$

then $a_1=6a_0+2=20$

$a_1=122$

$a_2=734$

adding all the terms implies

3+20+122+734+.....+(upto n terms)
I am stuck form here find  an explicit formula for a sequenc

Comment: What have you done so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг...when i was adding all these i am stuck to find a series of exolict formula

Comment: It looks to me as if you don’t understand what’s meant by the method of iteration. [This answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1145498/12042) shows an example of it applied to a sequence of the same general kind as yours.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott...Thanks i got it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Study the sequence $a_n - a_{n-1}$. It goes like $17, 102, 612$ etc. Do you see that this is a geometric series, with first term $17$ and constant ratio $6$?

Hence, $a_n- a_{n-1} = 17 \cdot 6^n$, you could say? Now figure out the general formula for $a_n$, and see if the additions work out. I'l give the answer in this "hidden hint":

> $a_n = \dfrac{17\cdot 6^n - 2}{5}$. The sum, up to $n$ terms, is $\dfrac{17\cdot 6^{n+1} -10n-27}{25}$.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

Look at the recursion -- it kind of looks like each term is about six times the previous term.  So factor out that behavior:  Let $a_n = 6^nb_n$.  (And since $a_0 = 3$, $b_0 = 3$.)

Your new equation becomes
$$
6^n b_n = 6\cdot6^{n-1} b_{n-1} + 2 \\
b_n = b_{n-1} + \frac{2}{6^{n}}
$$

Easier now?

Comment: .....thanks for your help