# Identity involving a recursive product

Tags: combinatorics, products, recursion

Here is yet another problem related to plane partitions. Given the recursive formula

$$
\begin{align*}
F(0)&=1,\\
F(r)&=\prod_{i=1}^r\frac{i+2r-1}{2i+r-2}F(r-1).
\end{align*}
$$

How can we prove

$$F(n)=\prod_{1\leq i\leq j\leq k\leq n}\frac{i+j+k-1}{i+j+k-2}\ ?$$

---

**EDIT**: The solution to this problem can be found in the answer section to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/402658/a-product-identity-involving-the-gamma-function/402680?noredirect=1#402680).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, note that, you can write the product as

$$\prod_{i=1}^r\frac{i+2r-1}{2i+r-2}= 2\,{\frac {\Gamma  \left( 3\,r \right) \Gamma \left( \frac{r}{2} \right) }
{{2}^{r+1}\Gamma  \left( \frac{3r}{2} \right) \Gamma  \left( 2\,r \right) }},$$

where $\Gamma(x)$ is the [gamma function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function). Second, you have a first order recurrence relation

$$ F(r) = g(r)F(r-1) $$

which can be solved using the [formula](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/366389/tricks-to-solve-arbitrary-recursions).

**Notes:**

1) $ \prod_{i=1}^r i =r!=\Gamma(r+1). $

2) $ \prod_{i=1}^r \frac{f(i)}{g(i)}=  \frac{\prod_{i=1}^rf(i)}{\prod_{i=1}^rg(i)}.  $

Comment: @CarlNajafi: I recommend to take a simple first order recurrence relation and try to apply the formula to it, so you can see what's going on. It is a good exercise. For instance, $u(n)=nu(n-1)$.