# Solving a recurrence relation (homework)

Tags: recurrence-relations

Solve the following recurrence relation:

$$l(n+1)=l(n)+π(4+2cn), \quad n=0,1,2,3,\ldots$$

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE. Can you tell us what you've tried in order to solve this?

Comment: i can solve linear reccurence relations  but l(n+1)=l(n)+ n types equation i couldnt find enough source and i guess my problem is nonlineer one after hours of search i thought i need some help

Comment: What does $\pi(4+2cn)$ represent in this question? The constant $\pi=3.14\ldots$ multiplied by $4+2cn$ where $c\in \mathbb{R}$ is some constant? Or perhaps $\pi(\ldots)$ is the [prime counting function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime-counting_function)? Hopefully by $\pi$ you don't mean some group-theoretic object?

Comment: i guess c is constant but there is no other information in the paper about this question so i dont know what  π represents either. but i will take it as a constant too.

Comment: See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/209640/solving-a-recurrence-relation-with-the-characteristic-equation/209652#209652) for general techniques.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rewrite the equation as:
$$
l(n + 1) - l(n) = \pi(4 + 2 c n)
$$
Thus:
$$
\begin{align*}
\sum_{0 \le k < n} (l(k + 1) - l(k))
  &= \sum_{0 \le k < n} \pi(4 + 2 c k) \\
l(n)
  &= l(0) + \sum_{0 \le k < n} \pi(4 + 2 c k)
\end{align*}
$$
Your recurrence is linear, al right.