# Recurrence Equation

Tags: recurrence-relations

I have a problem with this type of non-homogeneous equation.

Find the solution of recurrence equation:

$2 A_{n+1} = 3A_{n}-n+2$

$A_{0} = 1$

I know the idea behind the problem when the particular part is in the form that n is an exponent of some constant, but i don't know how to act with this.

Comment: As written now, it will reduce to $A_n = n$. I guess something is wrong in the OP or edit.

Comment: Maybe your recurrence equation has some problems?

Comment: First An is An+1

Comment: Edit is not good

Comment: Find the general solution of the homogeneous part of the equation and then try to find a particular solution with the Ansatz $A_n=an+b$.

Comment: @walcher So when i find the general solution(homogeneous part) i see the format of particular solution and add it to the first one?

Comment: @Filip: Follow the technique in [this problem](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/209640/solving-a-recurrence-relation-with-the-characteristic-equation).

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal I see where I had problems, it was the format of the particular solution that is in the equation, it seems clearer now. Thank you.

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal Can you please tell me why are we getting the problem in to the form that is in the only answer by easymath3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$ \frac{A_{n+1}}{\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^{n+1}} = \frac{A_{n}}{\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^{n}} + (1 - \frac{n}{2}) \left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^{n+1} $$

So you can add this equation from 1 to n.

Generally speaking, for recurrence equation $ a_{n+1} = p a_{n} + f(n) $, we let $ b_{n} = \frac{a_{n}}{p^n} $, so that $ b_{n+1} = b_{n} + \frac{f(n)}{p^{n+1}} $.

$$
\begin{aligned}
b_{n} - b_{n-1} & =  \frac{f(n-1)}{p^{n}} \\
b_{n-1} - b_{n-2} & =  \frac{f(n-2)}{p^{n-1}} \\
 &...  \\
b_{k} - b_{k-1} & =  \frac{f(k-1)}{p^{k}}\\
& ...  \\
b_{2} - b_{1} & =  \frac{f(1)}{p^{2}}
\end{aligned}
$$

So we get $ b_{n} = b_{1} + \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \frac{f(k)}{p^{k+1}} $

Comment: Can you please elaborate a little?

Comment: I understand, thank you.