# How to go about solving this recurrence relation?

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations, fibonacci-numbers

In my discrete math class we were given the problem of finding an explicit formula for this recurrence relation and proving its correctness via induction.
$$a_n=2a_{n-1}+a_{n-2}+1, a_1 = 1, a_2=1.$$
I feel confident that I could prove the correctness of the formula through induction but I have no idea what the formula is. What kind of strategy should I use for solving recurrence relations like this?

Comment: What do you mean with "solution"? Are you looking for an explicit formula for $a_n$?

Comment: Hoewever, you may take a look at this: https://oeis.org/A033539

Comment: Have you studied any techniques for solving recurrence relations?

Comment: You can use this [approach](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/209640/solving-a-recurrence-relation-with-the-characteristic-equation).

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal we haven't studied any techniques but most of the recurrence relations we've looked at have had fairly obvious formulas.

Comment: @user127.0.0.1 the homework said "solution" but I belive that the professor meant an explicit formula.

Comment: @CairnO: What I gave you is the standard technique to solve such type of recurrence relations.

Answer (score 2):

If you let $b_n=a_n+\frac 12$, the constant disappears. Then the characteristic polynomial is $r^2-2r-1=0$. Find its roots.

Answer (score 1):

If you've done linear algebra, there are techniques for solving *linear* recurrence relations. A (second order) linear recurrence is one of the form $a_{n+1}=\lambda a_n+\mu a_{n-1}$. This one isn't quite linear because of the $+1$, so let's try and remove that. The obvious way is to define:

$$b_{n+1}=2b_n+b_{n-1}$$

In the hopes that its behavior will reflect that of $a_n$ in a simple way. If you look at the error $\epsilon_n=a_n-b_n$:, you'll find that it satisfies the same recurrence relation as $a_n$, except that we get to pick the initial values of $\epsilon_n$, since this amounts to picking initial values of our simplified sequence $b_n$. So what initial values of $\epsilon_n$ would lead to a simple, predictable error term? Well, how about we look for initial values that will make $\epsilon_n$ a constant sequence? If you do the algebra, you'll find $\epsilon_1=\epsilon_2=-1/2$, and so we define:

$$b_1=a_1+1/2=3/2,\space b_2=a_2+1/2=3/2$$

So that now, $b_n=a_n+1/2$ for all $n$.

Anyway, now we have a linear recurrence relation. The idea of the linear algebra technique is to write:

$$B_n=\begin{pmatrix}b_{n+1}\\b_n\end{pmatrix}$$

So that we have:

$$B_n=\begin{pmatrix}2&1\\1&0\end{pmatrix}^{n-1}\begin{pmatrix}b_2\\b_1\end{pmatrix}$$

And then diagonalizing, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Use generating functions. Define $A(z) = \sum_{n \ge 0} a_n z^n$, write your recurrence as:
$$
a_{n + 2} = 2 a_{n + 1} + a_n + 1
$$
Multiply by $z^n$, sum over $n \ge 0$ and recognize the resulting sums:
$$
\frac{A(z) - a_0 - a_1 z}{z^2} = 2 \frac{A(z) - a_0}{z} + A(z) + \frac{1}{1 - z}
$$
Solve for $A(z)$:
$$
A(z) 
  = \frac{3}{4} \cdot \frac{1}{1 - (1 + \sqrt{2}) z}
      + \frac{3}{4} \cdot \frac{1}{1 - (1 - \sqrt{2}) z}
      - \frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{1}{1 - z}
$$
Everything in sight are geometric series:
$$
a_n
  = \frac{3}{4} \cdot (1 + \sqrt{2})^n
      + \frac{3}{4} \cdot (1 - \sqrt{2})^n
      - \frac{1}{2}
$$
Proof by induction is superfluous, the derivation is the proof.