# Particular solution of RE: $u_{n+1} - 2u_n = n^22^n$

Tags: sequences-and-series, operator-theory

Find the particular solution of recorrence equation $u_{n+1} - 2u_n = n^22^n$.

I am developing a practical method using operators $E$ e $\Delta$, defined by $E(u_n) = u_{n+1}$ and $\Delta(u_n) = u_{n+1} - u_n = (E - I)u_n$. I want to use these operators to find the particular solution of the above equation. Note that,

$$
u_{n+1} - 2u_n = (E - 2)u_n = n^22^n \quad \Rightarrow \quad u_{np} = \dfrac{1}{E - 2}n^22^n
$$
where $u_{np}$ is the particular solution. Would you like to discover how to work with the inverse operator for the particular solution. Thanks for any input.

Comment: I don't understand what $\frac{1}{E-2}$ means.

Comment: Being $E(u_n) = u_{n+1}$, then $\frac{1}{E}(u_{n+1}) = u_n$. I have proven that $\frac{1}{E + p}a^n = \frac{a^n}{a + p}$. I know not how to make sense in the case where it acts on a product of polynomial and exponential.

Comment: I'm not used to the notation $\frac{1}{E}$ meaning the inverse function $E^{-1}$.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with operator theory, but this is an answer using generating functions. First, define 
$$U(x)=\sum^{\infty}_{n=0}u_nx^n$$
Multiply the equation throughout by $x^n$ and sum up the terms from $0$ to $\infty$. We get
$$\sum^{\infty}_{n=0}u_{n+1}x^n- 2\sum^{\infty}_{n=0}u_nx^n=\sum^{\infty}_{n=0}n^2(2x)^n$$
The sum on the right hand side is simply 
$$(xD_x)^2\frac{1}{1-2x}$$
So
$$\frac{U(x)-u_0}{x}-2U(x)=\frac{4x^2+2x}{(1-2x)^3}$$
Solve for $U(x)$.
$$U(x)=\frac{4x^3+2x^2}{(1-2x)^4}+\frac{u_0}{1-2x}$$
Decompose the expression into partial fractions, extract the coefficient of $x^n$ and you get your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps define 
$$v_n=\frac{u_n}{2^{n-1}}.$$ 
Then the given relation becomes
$$v_{n+1}-v_{n}=n^2.$$
In your notation this means 
$$(E-I)v_n=n^2.$$
Thus
$$v_n=(E-I)^{-1}n^2.$$
Since $E$ is the difference operator then its inverse would be to increase the degree (like integration is inverse of differentiation). Thus $v_n$ should be an appropriate cubic polynomial. Something like
$$v_n=\frac{n^3}{3}-\frac{n^2}{2}+\frac{n}{6}.$$

Comment: His answer was very useful because, $\frac{1}{E - I}n^2 = \frac{1}{\Delta}(n^2-n+n)= \frac{1}{\Delta}[2{n \choose 2} - {n \choose 1}] = 2{n\choose 3} - {n \choose 2}$. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you advance.

$$ u_{np} = \dfrac{1}{E - 2}n^22^n = -\frac{1}{2} \left( 1-\frac{E}{2} \right)^{-1}n^22^n $$

$$ =-\frac{1}{2} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{E^k}{2^k}n^22^n = -\frac{1}{2} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^k}(n+k)^2\,2^{n+k}$$

$$ = -\frac{2^n}{2}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(n+k)^2=-\frac{2^n}{2}\sum_{m=n}^{\infty} m^2  $$

$$ = -\frac{2^n}{2}\left( \sum_{m=1}^{\infty} m^2 -  \sum_{m=1}^{n-1} m^2 \right) $$

$$ = -\frac{2^n}{2}\left( \zeta(-2) -(n^3/3-n^2/2+n/6) \right)\quad (\mathrm{ note\, 1 }) $$

> $$\implies u_{np} = \frac{2^nn}{2}(n^2/3-n/2+1/6) \quad (\mathrm{ note\, 2 }). $$

Compare with [other techniques](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/209640/solving-a-recurrence-relation-with-the-characteristic-equation).

**Notes:**

1) The [zeta function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function) is defined by

> $$ \zeta( s) = \sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{m^s}. $$

2) For negative even numbers $-2n, \forall n\in\mathbb {N}$ the zeta function equals $0$; i.e

> $$ \zeta( -2n) = 0. $$

Comment: Wonderful way to solve the problem. I really like resollver ODE and RE through operational methods. I see that you also know a lot about it. I will present soon other issues to be discussed. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @MathFacts: You are welcome.

Comment: Yes, I love this theme.