# Homework - Resolve the recurrence relation

Tags: recurrence-relations

What's the closed formula of this recurrence relation?
$$a_n = a_{n-1}+2a_{n-2}+2^n \text{ with } a_0=1, a_1=2 $$

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: Why do you think there exists a closed formula?

Comment: So far, I don't understand how I can find the closed formula.

Comment: If you know how to do the first part of that, you should say so in the question so that readers can gauge your understanding. (Plus, writing out the first few terms usually helps to clarify the solution.)

Comment: Do you know how to use characterisstic equation, in this case $x^2-x-2=0$? We don't *really* need it in this case, guess and verify might work.

Comment: @AndréNicolas: It might still help in this case due to the inhomogenous part.

Comment: I know I need to use characterisstic equation, but I don't how to use it. Can you help me?

Comment: @AndréNicolas have deleted my comment on your deleted comment ...

Comment: [Here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/209640/solving-a-recurrence-relation-with-the-characteristic-equation) is a technique.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is nonhomogeneneous difference equations. First solve the homogeneous equation
$$
a_n - a_{n-1} - 2a_{n-2} = 0 \quad (1)
$$
Let $a_n = r^n$, so that $a_{n-1} = r^{n-1}$ and $r_{n-2} = r^{n-2} = 0$. Replacing in (1), we have
$$
r^n - r^{n-1} - 2r^{n-2} = 0 \quad r^2 - r - 2 = 0 \quad \Rightarrow \ r_1 = -1, \ r_2 = 2
$$ 
$$
a_{nh} = C_1(-1)^n + C_22^n
$$
Particular solution: Let $a_{np} = a_n = An2^n$. The presence of n is due to the fact that $2$ is a root of the equation (1). So, $a_{n-1} = A(n-1)2^{n-1}$ and $a_{n-2} = A(n-2)2^{n-2}$. Substituting in the given equation, we have
$$
An2^n + (An - A)2^{n-1} - 2A(n-2)2^{n-2} = 2^n \quad \Rightarrow \quad A = \frac{2}{3}
$$
Thus, $a_n = a_{nh} + a_{np} = C_1(-1)^n + C_22^n + \frac{2n2^n}{3}$. But, $a_0 = a(0) = 1$ and $a_1 = a(1) = 2$. We have the system
$$
\begin{cases}
1 = a_0 = C_1 + C_2\\
2 = a_1 = -C_1 + C_2  + \frac{8}{3}
\end{cases}
\quad \Rightarrow \quad C_1 = 8/9, \quad C_2 = 1/9
$$
Thus,
$$
a_n = \frac{8(-1)^n}{9} + \frac{1}{9}2^n + \frac{2n2^n}{3}
$$

Comment: You must have committed a mistake somewhere. According to WolframAlpha, [this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=a_n+%3D+a_%7Bn-1%7D%2B2a_%7Bn-2%7D%2B2%5En%2C+a_0%3D1%2C+a_1%3D2) is the solution.

Comment: I decided very quickly and missed the constant value. This new version is now corrected.

Answer (score 7):

A generating function approach would make this straightforward:

$$G(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n x^n = 1+2x+\sum_{n=2}^\infty a_n x^n$$
$$=1+2x+\sum_{n=2}^\infty (a_{n-1} + 2a_{n-2} + 2^n)x^n$$
$$=1+2x+\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n x^{n+1} + 2 \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n x^{n+2} + \sum_{n=2}^\infty 2^n x^n$$
$$=1+2x+x(G(x)-1)+2x^2G(x)+\frac{2^2x^2}{1-2x}$$

Thus $$G(x)(1-x-2x^2) = 1+x+\frac{2^2x^2}{1-2x}$$ and $$G(x) = \frac{1+x}{1-x-2x^2} + \frac{2^2x^2}{(1-2x)(1-x-2x^2)} = \frac{1+x}{(1+x)(1-2x)} + \frac{2^2x^2}{(1-2x)(1+x)(1-2x)}$$
$$= \frac{1}{(1-2x)} + \frac{2^2x^2}{(1-2x)^2(1+x)}$$

Now you can use partial fractions, and then expand in terms of geometric series to find the taylor coefficients of $G(x)$ which are the terms $a_n$.

Comment: Are you sure there's not an easy way because I really don't understand your approach.

Comment: This is a standard approach for linear recurrence relations. The idea is that $G(x)$ stores the information of the $a_n$'s in its taylor coefficients. Then you try to use the recurrence to rewrite $G(x)$ into an easier form (in this case a rational function). What is your background?

Comment: It's the standard form if you really want to do well at it, anyways. An intro discrete math course might gloss that, I guess.

Comment: @hlapointe Joel's is a very good solution, you should check out generating functions. the underlying idea is not difficult to grasp, and for motivation, this problem is a good illustration of the power of the technique.

Comment: That's a problem of my discrete math class.

Comment: Ok. I wil try to studie this approach.

Comment: Wolfram Alpha says that $a_n = (4(-1)^n+(6n+5)2^n)/9$. It seems to be very tricky.

Comment: That is the sort of answer you would expect for this kind of problem.

Comment: The only novelty in this particular case is the small annouyance of the $n 2^n$.

Comment: @hlapointe [generatingfunctionology](http://www.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/gfology2.pdf) is a very good book on this topic.

Answer (score 4):

The best course of action for simple inhomogeneous recurrences is to make use of a smart "change of variables" (read: substitute with another recurrence relation) to turn it into a homogeneous recurrence. A nice observation here is to notice that **$2^n$ is itself a recurrence relation**, namely:

$$y_n=2y_{n-1},\,\,(y_0=1)$$ 
Let's use this to our advantage:

$$\begin{align}
a_n=a_{n-1}+2a_{n-2}+2^n &\Leftrightarrow 2^n=a_n-a_{n-1}-2a_{n-2} \\
&\Leftrightarrow 2\cdot2^{n-1}=a_n-a_{n-1}-2a_{n-2} \\
&\Leftrightarrow 2\cdot (a_{n-1}-a_{n-2}-2a_{n-3})=a_n-a_{n-1}-2a_{n-2} \\
&\Leftrightarrow a_n-3a_{n-1}+4a_{n-3}=0
\end{align}$$

Bam, homogeneous recurrence. Can apply the characteristic equation and finish it by yourself?

**Edit:** The characteristic equation for the last recurrence is $x^3-3x+4=0$, whose roots are $2,2$ and $-1$. It is well-known then, that given these roots, the solution is of the form:
$$a_n=(An+B)2^n+C(-1)^n$$

For some constants $A,B,C$. To find out what the constants are, we plug in values of $n$ for which the value of $a_n$ is known. The values of $a_0,a_1$ were given, but we need three to solve a linear system with three variables. We can easily calculate $a_2$: $$a_2=a_1+2a_0+2^2=8$$

Now we solve the system:

$$\begin{cases}
(A\cdot0+B)2^0+C(-1)^0=1 \\
(A\cdot1+B)2^1+C(-1)^1=2 \Rightarrow \\
(A\cdot2+B)2^2+C(-1)^2=8
\end{cases}$$

$$\Rightarrow \begin{cases}
B+C=1 \\
2(A+B)-C=2 \\
4(2A+B)+C=8
\end{cases}$$

Solving this will yield $A=\frac{2}{3}$,$B=\frac{5}{9}$ and $C=\frac{4}{9}$. Therefore, the closed form is:
$$a_n=\frac{(6n+5)2^n+4(-1)^n}{9}$$

Comment: Not really. I barely understand your manipulations. Can you show me how to apply the characteristic equation?

Comment: Sorry, I commited an arithmetic mistake. It should be fixed now. The characteristic equation for the last recurrence is $x^3-3x+4=0$, whose roots are $-1$ and $2$ (with double multiplicity). You can use it to solve the last recurrence.

Comment: One point that's well-worth mulling: how is the characteristic equation in this case related to the one you had from the original relation?

Comment: Do you understand it now? The only manipulation I did was to isolate $2^n$ and see that $2^n=a_n-a_{n-1}-2a_{n-2}$. With this we can infer that $2^{n-1}=a_{n-1}-a_{n-2}-2a_{n-3}$, and so we substitute it and the $2^n$ is gone. That was the whole motivation after all: I was assuming you were comfortable with solving linear homogeneous recurrences (since you said you knew about the characteristic polynomial).