# Solve recurrence equation $T(n)=2T(n-1)-4$

Tags: recurrence-relations, nonlinear-system

I got such recurrence equation which I cannot solve, I tried with mathematical induction, but I've got information, that this one is not linear and cannot be solve like that. And really have no idea how to do it.

$ \begin{cases}
T(1)=1 \\
T(n)=2T(n-1)-4
\end{cases}$

Comment: The first part of [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/351868/12042), giving two elementary methods of solving a similar recurrence, should give you the tools that you need.

Answer (score 1):

Compute the first terms of the sequence:
$$1 \qquad -2 \qquad -8 \qquad -20 \qquad -44 \dots$$
And then look at the difference between next terms, getting
$$3 \qquad 6 \qquad 12 \qquad 24 \qquad \dots$$

This sequence has a very familiar pattern, since you can see that every term is the double of the previous term.

So that the $n$-th terms should be

$$T(n)=1- (3+6+12+ \dots 3 \cdot 2^{n-2}) = 1-3(2^{n-1}-1) = 4 - 3\cdot2^{n-1}$$

After conjectured this, the last thing to do is to check that this is the correct solution: so plug it into the recursive definition of $T(n)$ and check that everything works.

Comment: **Must be** isn't really right. It would be better to say that these numerical data very strongly suggest the conjecture that your closed form is correct; properly speaking, it still needs to be proved, e.g., by induction.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the substitution method:

$$T(n)=2T(n-1) -4 \\
= 2(2T(n-2)-4)-4 \\
= 4T(n-2)-8 \\
= 2(4T(n-3)-4)-8\\
= 8T(n-3)-12\\
= \ ...\\
= 2^kT(n-k)-4k \ \ \ (\mbox{for} \ n\ge k \ge 1) $$

If we set $k=n$, we get:
$$T(n)= 2^nT(n-n)-4n = 2^n\overbrace{T(0)}^{1}-4n = 2^n-4n$$

Note: I assumed $T(0)=1$. If you are not allowed to assume that, you can't just set $k=n$.

Comment: It is not an answer!

Comment: $= 4T(n-2)\color{red}{-8}\;$ $\;$ That should be $\color{red}{-12}$ instead, and the same error gets repeated below.

Answer (score 0):

The recurrence can be rewritten as:

$$
T(n) = 2\,T(n-1)-4 \quad\iff\quad T(n)-4=2\cdot\big(T(n-1)-4\big)
$$

It follows that $\,T(n)-4\,$ is a geometric progression with common ratio $\,2\,$, so:

$$
T(n)-4 \;=\; 2^{n-1} \cdot\big(T(1) - 4\big) \;=\; -3 \cdot 2^{n-1}
$$