# Solve this recursion

Tags: recursion

\begin{cases}
T(1) = 1 \\
T(n) = 2T(n-1)-4
\end{cases}
Solve this recursion using summation factor method or iterative method.
Could someone solve for me this recursion and explain all steps?

Comment: I don't think plainly stating the problem and asking for 'all steps' is going to bode well for you on this site. Show your work, and explain your confusion. You may get some hints

Comment: Related: [Solve recurrence equation $T(n)=2T(n-1)-4$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1157319/solve-recurrence-equation-tn-2tn-1-4)

Answer (score 1):

$$T(n)=2T(n-1)-4$$

$$T(n-1)=2T(n-2)-4$$

$$T(n-2)=2T(n-3)-4$$

$$\dots$$

$$T(n-i)=2T(n-(i+1))-4$$

SO:

$$T(n)=2(2T(n-2)-4)-4=2^2T(n-2)-2 \cdot 4-4=2^2(2T(n-3)-4)-2 \cdot 4-4=2^3T(n-3)-2^2 \cdot 4- 2 \cdot 4-4= \dots= 2^iT(n-i)- \sum_{k=0}^{i-1} 2^k \cdot 4$$

The recursions ends for $n-i=1 \Rightarrow i=n-1$.

Can you continue?

Answer (score -1):

Because of the $2T(n-1)$ it almost looks like $T(n)$ will be roughly $2^{n-1}$ (I use $n-1$ because $T(1)$ is $1$ not $2$).

So let$$R(n) = 2^{n-1}R(n)$$
The recursion becomes
$$
2^{n-1}R(n) = 2\cdot 2^{n-2}R(n-1) -4 \\ R(1) = 1
$$
Divide thru by $2^{n-1}R(n) $ to get
$$
R(n) = R(n-1) - \frac{4}{2^{n-1}} 
$$
So
$$R(n) = 1 - \sum_{k=2}^n\frac{4}{2^{k-1}} = 1 - 4\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}\frac{1}{2^{j}} 
= 1 - 4 \left( 1 - \frac{1}{2^{n-1}}\right) = \frac{1}{2^{n-3}} - 3
$$
And substitute back:
$$
T(n) = 2^{n-1} \left( \frac{1}{2^{n-3}} - 3 \right) = 4 - 3\cdot 2^{n-1}
$$

Comment: I think you mean $T(n) = 2^{n-1}R(n)$. Also, $T(n) = 2^{n-k}R(n)$ works, for any fixed $k$. I Was going to use $k=0$ until you beat me to it.