# Recurrence Relations and Characteristic Equations

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

I am not understanding how to go from the beginning of a recurrence relation to the end. I do not understand how to get to the characteristic equation. I can factor it if I know where it comes from.

Thank you.

Comment: IMHO, it will be way too long to properly cover the recurrence relation/characteristic equation here. You should learn this from a book or lecture or watch this [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pErXD1Q_HYI) as a start.

Comment: I'll try the video. I am trying with my book but just not quite getting it. Thank you!

Comment: See the [detailed answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/373815/finding-the-closed-form-for-a-sequence).

Comment: There are plenty of examples of recurrences here, look at the techniques used. The "characteristic equation" method works, but there are less error-prone techniques available.

Answer (score 1):

I got it from the video! to get the characteristic equation you use an=x^2 term an-1=x term and the an-2= constant term. Then you can factor for the roots.

Answer (score 1):

Look here:
http://www.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/DownldGF.html

The downloadable book
at this site,
Generatingfunctionology,
will tell you more than you need to know.

Comment: It’s a lovely book, but it’s unlikely to be helpful to the OP, especially if she’s had some trouble following the topic in one of the usual undergraduate discrete math texts: it’s simply written at much too high a level of sophistication.